# Grouping data in collection in one format into one of another

Tags: javascript, collections, lodash

Say I have this collection:

```
{
    collections: [
        {
            collection_name: "One",
            url_slug: "one",
            collection_type: "group-one",
            id: 700001
        }, {
            collection_name: "Two",
            url_slug: "two",
            collection_type: "group-one",
            id: 700002
        }, {
            collection_name: "Three",
            url_slug: "three",
            collection_type: "group-one",
            id: 700003
        }, {
            collection_name: "Four",
            url_slug: "four",
            collection_type: "group-one",
            id: 700004
        }, {
            collection_name: "Five",
            url_slug: "five",
            collection_type: "group-one",
            id: 700005
        }, {
            collection_name: "Six",
            url_slug: "six",
            collection_type: "group-one",
            id: 700006
        }, {
            collection_name: "Seven",
            url_slug: "seven",
            collection_type: "group-two",
            id: 700007
        }, {
            collection_name: "Eight",
            url_slug: "eight",
            collection_type: "group-three",
            id: 700008
        }, {
            collection_name: "Nine",
            url_slug: "nine",
            collection_type: "group-three",
            id: 700009
        }, {
            collection_name: "Ten",
            url_slug: "ten",
            collection_type: "group-four",
            id: 700010
        }
    ]
}
```

… and I need to take that data and create a new group of collections using the `collection_type` value as the key for each new collection:

```
{
    "group-one": [
        {
            collection_name: "One",
            url_slug: "one",
            id: 700001
        }, {
            collection_name: "Two",
            url_slug: "two",
            id: 700002
        }, {
            collection_name: "Three",
            url_slug: "three",
            id: 700003
        }, {
            collection_name: "Four",
            url_slug: "four",
            id: 700004
        }, {
            collection_name: "Five",
            url_slug: "five",
            id: 700005
        }, {
            collection_name: "Six",
            url_slug: "six",
            id: 700006
        }
    ],
    "group-two": [
        {
            collection_name: "Seven",
            url_slug: "seven",
            id: 700007
        }
    ],
    "group-three": [
        {
            collection_name: "Eight",
            url_slug: "eight",
            id: 700008
        }, {
            collection_name: "Nine",
            url_slug: "nine",
            id: 700009
        }
    ],
    "group-four": [
            {
            collection_name: "Ten",
            url_slug: "ten",
            id: 700010
        }
    ]
}
```

Besides just creating a new object, looping through the original and pushing entries to keys in that new object, is there a simpler, more concise method — possibly using Lodash — to knock this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution using native `Array#forEach`.

```js
const data = {"collections":[{"collection_name":"One","url_slug":"one","collection_type":"group-one","id":700001},{"collection_name":"Two","url_slug":"two","collection_type":"group-one","id":700002},{"collection_name":"Three","url_slug":"three","collection_type":"group-one","id":700003},{"collection_name":"Four","url_slug":"four","collection_type":"group-one","id":700004},{"collection_name":"Five","url_slug":"five","collection_type":"group-one","id":700005},{"collection_name":"Six","url_slug":"six","collection_type":"group-one","id":700006},{"collection_name":"Seven","url_slug":"seven","collection_type":"group-two","id":700007},{"collection_name":"Eight","url_slug":"eight","collection_type":"group-three","id":700008},{"collection_name":"Nine","url_slug":"nine","collection_type":"group-three","id":700009},{"collection_name":"Ten","url_slug":"ten","collection_type":"group-four","id":700010}]};
const obj = {};

data.collections.forEach(({ collection_type, ...z }) => {
  (obj[collection_type] || (obj[collection_type] = [])).push({
    ...z,
  });
})

console.log(obj);
```

Or `Array#reduce`.

```js
const data = {"collections":[{"collection_name":"One","url_slug":"one","collection_type":"group-one","id":700001},{"collection_name":"Two","url_slug":"two","collection_type":"group-one","id":700002},{"collection_name":"Three","url_slug":"three","collection_type":"group-one","id":700003},{"collection_name":"Four","url_slug":"four","collection_type":"group-one","id":700004},{"collection_name":"Five","url_slug":"five","collection_type":"group-one","id":700005},{"collection_name":"Six","url_slug":"six","collection_type":"group-one","id":700006},{"collection_name":"Seven","url_slug":"seven","collection_type":"group-two","id":700007},{"collection_name":"Eight","url_slug":"eight","collection_type":"group-three","id":700008},{"collection_name":"Nine","url_slug":"nine","collection_type":"group-three","id":700009},{"collection_name":"Ten","url_slug":"ten","collection_type":"group-four","id":700010}]};

const res = data.collections.reduce((s, { collection_type, ...z }) => {
  (s[collection_type] || (s[collection_type] = [])).push({
    ...z,
  });
  return s;
}, {})

console.log(res);
```

And finally - ES5 solution (without ES6 features).

```js
var data = {"collections":[{"collection_name":"One","url_slug":"one","collection_type":"group-one","id":700001},{"collection_name":"Two","url_slug":"two","collection_type":"group-one","id":700002},{"collection_name":"Three","url_slug":"three","collection_type":"group-one","id":700003},{"collection_name":"Four","url_slug":"four","collection_type":"group-one","id":700004},{"collection_name":"Five","url_slug":"five","collection_type":"group-one","id":700005},{"collection_name":"Six","url_slug":"six","collection_type":"group-one","id":700006},{"collection_name":"Seven","url_slug":"seven","collection_type":"group-two","id":700007},{"collection_name":"Eight","url_slug":"eight","collection_type":"group-three","id":700008},{"collection_name":"Nine","url_slug":"nine","collection_type":"group-three","id":700009},{"collection_name":"Ten","url_slug":"ten","collection_type":"group-four","id":700010}]};

var res = data.collections.reduce(function(s, a) {
  (s[a.collection_type] || (s[a.collection_type] = [])).push({
    id: a.id,
    collection_name: a.collection_name,
    url_slug: a.url_slug,
  });
  return s;
}, {})

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Why not Array#reduce?

Comment: @OriDrori Any difference? Anyways - I just wonder if the logic inside `push` can be simplified somehow. With destructuring or anything.

Comment: @OriDrori Yep I did it :o)

Comment: You are reducing an array to an object.  You can use object rest spread, but it's still in proposal stage, and needs babel.

Comment: @OriDrori Yeah, I know. Object destructuring is amazing, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed it is, but this is more [object rest/spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) :) And it's ES6.

Comment: I've added ES5 solution, for compatibility purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash, you can try something like this:

```
var data = {collections: {...}};

var group = _(data.collections)
                .groupBy('collection_type')
                .forEach(function(records, groupName) {
                   // clean up/modify records
                   records.forEach(function(record) { 
                     delete record['collection_type']; 
                   });
                 });
```

> [run on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okk3grk1/)

P.S. older lodash versions may require `.value()` at the end of the chain `_(...).groupBy().forEach().value()`